# Power Automate - Copy Files but ignore if already exists (basically a sync files via Flow)

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

Attempting to copy any MISSING files over from one SharePoint Shared Documents Folder to another.   I have a separate flow that looks for all NEW files every 30 minutes and copies them over.  However, occasionally the flow will miss a document because the flow ran slow, or the like.   Therefore, I would like to manually trigger a similar flow that will copy over any files that does not exist today.

I get to the SharePoint Copy File step. The only choices are to 'Copy file with new name', 'Fail this action", or 'Replace".   It does also give a "Custom Action" as well...but that is where I am struggling.

I need it to basically, IGNORE / DO NOTHING if the file name already exists... How can I do that?

[image: ScreenShot of Copy File]

Answer (score 0):

Unsure if you're still having this issue as it's been quite a while. but i had a similiar issue. i've been able to resolve mine by adding an http request before the copy action and then using a condition based on the status code. [Http request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCCSm.png) in this image you see the site adress which for your problem would be the destination site adress and then you find the Uri which grabs everything after .com (expression used split(variables('ListUrl'), '.com')['1']) which just grabs everything after .com. since mine was dynamically selected. and then takes the other parts which in my case was Gedeelde Documenten. (dutch) and then the document name you're trying to check for. then after that i use a condition to check wether the status is 404 (which is that the document isn't there) with the expression (outputs('Send_an_HTTP_Request_to_SharePoint')['statusCode']
) giving us the output of the http request. don't forget to configure next action so it runs after a failed as well

Hope this helps.